# Force AMP email render the desktop version on Gmail for mobile

Tags: gmail, html-email, amp-html, amp-email

I used to code my usual emails at 520px, without responsive media queries and use a fix for Gmail that was forcing it to render the desktop version.

I've converted one of the emails to AMP4email, fully validated it on AMP playground, however, when I send a live test from the playground to my Gmail account, the email is not resizing to fit the device, it takes more on the right than the viewport. This is probably due to how AMP works vs the old HTML that contained lot of !important attributes to make it work on the majority of the email clients.

Is there a way to force rendering the desktop version on Gmail app for AMP emails?

Comment: You shouldn't need a lot of !importants to make your email work. I suspect the best way forward woudl be to post a basic version of your email (the code).

Comment: I ended up writing media queries to make it work, I couldn't find a workaround for AMP emails.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that Gmail doesn't do any auto-zooming for AMP emails that have a width that's larger than the device width. This exists as a feature for static HTML emails as a last resort for unresponsive and/or inaccessible emails that could've been better designed. With AMP for Email, the hope is that developers would make their emails better by designing responsive and accessible emails without the need to resort to the email clients doing the work for them.

For the same reason, pinch-to-zoom is also not supported for AMP emails in Gmail mobile clients. As a result, even if the Gmail auto-resizes the email to fit the device width, the content of the email would likely be inaccessible for the recipient (e.g., text could be too small).